# Javafx: applying image to meshview not working

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-3d

I am trying to apply the image to my meshview cube with phongmaterial but only the black cube with no colour is showing up on the screen. It used to work with the Box and a cube, but now its not working with them too.

And also, Can anyone tell me how to get the specific cube's faces??

Here is my code:

```
Rotate rxBox = new Rotate(30, 0, 0, 0, Rotate.X_AXIS);
Rotate ryBox = new Rotate(50, 0, 0, 0, Rotate.Y_AXIS);
Rotate rzBox = new Rotate(30, 0, 0, 0, Rotate.Z_AXIS);

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


    float hw = 100/2f;
    float hh = 100/2f;
    float hd = 100/2f;

    float points[] = {
            hw, hh, hd,
            hw, hh, -hd,
            hw, -hh, hd,
            hw, -hh, -hd,
            -hw, hh, hd,
            -hw, hh, -hd,
            -hw, -hh, hd,
            -hw, -hh, -hd};

    float tex[] = {
            100, 0,
            200, 0,
            0, 100,
            100, 100,
            200, 100,
            300, 100,
            400, 100,
            0, 200,
            100, 200,
            200, 200,
            300, 200,
            400, 200,
            100, 300,
            200, 300};

    int faces[] = {
            0, 10, 2, 5, 1, 9,
            2, 5, 3, 4, 1, 9,
            4, 7, 5, 8, 6, 2,
            6, 2, 5, 8, 7, 3,
            0, 13, 1, 9, 4, 12,
            4, 12, 1, 9, 5, 8,
            2, 1, 6, 0, 3, 4,
            3, 4, 6, 0, 7, 3,
            0, 10, 4, 11, 2, 5,
            2, 5, 4, 11, 6, 6,
            1, 9, 3, 4, 5, 8,
            5, 8, 3, 4, 7, 3};

    int[] facesSmoothingGroups = {0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5};

   // URL resource = Main.class.getResource("DFv8z.png");
    Image diffuseMap = new Image(Main.class.getResource("PCmIW.png").toExternalForm());

    TriangleMesh mesh = new TriangleMesh();
    mesh.getPoints().addAll(points);
    mesh.getTexCoords().addAll(tex);
    mesh.getFaces().addAll(faces);
   // mesh.getFaceSmoothingGroups().addAll(facesSmoothingGroups);

    Material cubeMaterial = new PhongMaterial(Color.TRANSPARENT, diffuseMap, null, null, null);

    MeshView m = new MeshView(mesh);
    m.getTransforms().addAll(rxBox, ryBox, rzBox);
    m.setMaterial(cubeMaterial);

    final Group g = new Group(m);

    g.setTranslateX(400/2);
    g.setTranslateY(400/2);
    //g.setTranslateZ(400/2);
    g.setRotationAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS);
    g.setRotationAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);
    //g.setRotationAxis(Rotate.Z_AXIS);




    Scene scene = new Scene(g, 400, 400, Color.SKYBLUE);


    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

[image: Here is the image i want to use.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track but you need to:

- Use normalized texture coordinates, between 0.0f and 1.0f
- Don't set the diffuse color to transparent, just set the diffuse map image.

For the first part, just define the total length and height of the net image:

```
float L = 400f;
float H = 300f;
```

and then normalize the texture coordinates:

```
float tex[] = {
        100f / L,   0f / H,
        200f / L,   0f / H,
          0f / L, 100f / H,
        100f / L, 100f / H,
        200f / L, 100f / H,
        300f / L, 100f / H,
        400f / L, 100f / H,
          0f / L, 200f / H,
        100f / L, 200f / H,
        200f / L, 200f / H,
        300f / L, 200f / H,
        400f / L, 200f / H,
        100f / L, 300f / H,
        200f / L, 300f / H};
```

For the second part, just use the setter:

```
PhongMaterial cubeMaterial = new PhongMaterial();
cubeMaterial.setDiffuseMap(diffuseMap);
```

And you have your textured cube (enabling the smoothing groups):

[image: Textured cube]

**EDIT**

In order to find out the top face, after any possible rotation, this can be done easily if you define the current colors and normals, based on the net image and the order of how faces are defined:

```
final String[] colors = {"Blue", "Red", "White", "Yellow", "Cyan", "Green"};

float normals[] = {
     1f,  0f,  0f,
    -1f,  0f,  0f,
     0f,  1f,  0f,
     0f, -1f,  0f,
     0f,  0f,  1f,
     0f,  0f, -1f,
};
```

Then, you want to track the top face, which corresponds to the normal `{0, -1, 0}` in scene coordinates.

So basically you need to express that normal in the mesh coordinates:

```
Point3D normal = m.sceneToLocal(0, -1, 0);
```

and finally you have to match this normal to any of those defined in `normals`. The index of that one will give you the color:

```
private String getColor(MeshView m, float[] normals) {

    Point3D normal = m.sceneToLocal(0, -1, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < normals.length; i += 3) {
        if (normals[i] * normal.getX() + normals[i+1] * normal.getY() + normals[i+2] * normal.getZ() > 0.99) {
            return colors[i / 3];
        }
    }
    return "no color found";
}
```

Comment: Hi jose, the image is now working fine. but when i roll the dice randomly, I want to print out the colour which is on top. I tried to return the face but it returns the total number of face.

Comment: If you scale the texture coordinates properly (between 0-1) you should get the pic I posted. You get the net over _each_ face, if you divide your texture coordinates by **100**, not by L (400) or H (300).

Comment: How to use faceSmoothingGroups to track which side is on top?

Comment: For that use `PickResult`. From a Mouse event like clicked or pressed, you can get for instance `event.getPickResult().getIntersectedFace()`. Don't need the smoothing groups for that. Just do: `m.setOnMouseClicked(e -> System.out.println("e " + e.getPickResult().getIntersectedFace()));`

Comment: Great, consider then accepting the answer, so it can be useful as well for others.

Comment: Hi Jose, I've got one last question. How do we track the top of the cube's face without mouse event. with the camera or when the dice is rolled and lie flat 180 degree at the bottom. I want to return the colour of the dice that is on the top. Could you help me on this one, Please? Thanks

Comment: how do i return, which colour is on top of the dice?