# How to create a box with two different pictures(same size) on the top and bottom of the box?

Tags: java, javafx, 3d, fxgl

I just want to create a box in javafx. That box has two different pictures(at same size) on top and bottom (It's no need to be only on top or bottom because the box can rotate, just at two opposite faces). Just like the two covers of a book.
I thought there are various methods but I don't know how to write the code and which is best. These methods are on below:

1. Use two MeshView and two textures.
2. Combine the two pictures in a new texture and use one MeshView.

I tried to use the phongmeterial in Javafx but it painted the six faces with one picture(six times), that not what I thought.
I expect a box with two pictures on top and bottom with other faces in white.

Comment: See [this cube example with a MeshView on p25-30](https://www.slideshare.net/jpt1122/con2221-weaver-exploringjavafx3d).  To create the texture used containing two images, you can paint the two images on a canvas in a scene, then snapshot the canvas or scene.

Comment: It is a different question, but somewhat similar because the concepts involved are the same, see [How to color some triangles in a TriangleMesh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69305387/how-to-color-some-triangles-in-a-trianglemesh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For 3D boxes:**

Please take a look at this thread:
[Javafx: applying image to meshview not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47946126/javafx-applying-image-to-meshview-not-working)

**For 2D boxes:**

Use a `BorderPane`. Put the top `Image` into the top part and the bottom `Image` into to bottom part. The center is used for your content (or spacing element).

You can rotate the complete element.
The spacing element could be a simple `vbox` with a fixed height.

Comment: Thanks, but this is a 3d question. I mean top and bottom just like the two covers of a book

Comment: May be I should rewrite this question

Comment: Did you mean a 3 dimensional box? That was my mistake. In this case I would like to redirect you to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47946126/javafx-applying-image-to-meshview-not-working.

Comment: Please take a look at my updated answer!

Comment: Oh thanks! I'll have a look